# Establish a listen live function to a university radio station

Tags: audio-streaming

I was asked to implement a website for a radio station of my university. The website should have a listen live stream as and displaying the current song playing and the related tags for facebook and tweeter. After researching the subject i found multible ways for establishing the listen live with softwares like  winamp or southcast. **The problem is that i have to establish the listen live connection without opening a port on the University's Server.** 
Do you have any ideas how to implement this task?

Thanks 
Constantinos

Comment: Since you should create a website, I guess port 80 is available, so streaming over http should be the way to go

Comment: I know but due to the regulation of the university they wont let any incoming ports to the server. What i should do instead?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you're hosting something, so opening a port is necessary.  No way around it.  However, as Eugen mentioned, you can run your server on port 80.

I suggest using SHOUTcast for your server software.  It's light-weight, and is highly compatible.  The SHOUTcast protocol is essentially HTTP with a few modifications.  Most firewall software recognizes it as such, and you should have no issues with running it on port 80.  In fact, you are encouraged to do so, for those that listen to your stream, as those listening are often behind packet shapers and firewalls that allow port 80, but slow down or block others.

For the website, you can use whatever you want.  PHP is always a good method for this, as it is easy to learn for students, but there are plenty of other choices.

If you have any questions that are specific to your situation, feel free to e-mail me at brad@musatcha.com.  I'd be happy to help.  If you have programming questions though, post them here so that everyone can learn.

Comment: First of all i would like to thank you brad for answering my question. I found out your answer really helpfull. I will consider your thoughts and i will come back to ask you for any particular problem i have.